# Cocoapods / Swift: which import statement?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I am migrating my Swift project to Swift 1.2 and I have chosen to switch to use the `use_frameworks!` option in CocoaPods.

Among the pods I have:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!
platform :ios, '8.0'

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 1.2'
pod 'SCLAlertView-Objective-C', '~> 0.3'
```

My question is, with the second pod name how can I import it?

For a name without dash it's pretty obvious, `import Alamofire` but for the other one it's tougher ... What is the rule to follow?

I know that `SCLAlertView` is also shipped in a Swift flavor, my question is not for that specific package, it is more general.